# Validation loss not changing in Resnet

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, resnet

So I have data like in the shape of (25000, 178, 178, 3) where I have 25000 samples and each have 3 different color channel(not the RGB one), where I have around 21k samples with label 0 and rest 4k as label 1. Here's one of my sample data:

```
array([[[[1.79844797e-01, 1.73587397e-01, 1.73587397e-01, ...,
          4.84393053e-02, 5.15680127e-02, 5.46967126e-02],
         [1.76716089e-01, 1.79844797e-01, 1.82973504e-01, ...,
          5.15680127e-02, 5.31323589e-02, 5.15680127e-02],
         [1.81409150e-01, 1.86102197e-01, 1.81409150e-01, ...,
          5.15680127e-02, 5.31323589e-02, 5.15680127e-02]]],


       [[[2.51065755e+00, 2.53197193e+00, 2.53197193e+00, ...,
          1.88543844e+00, 1.89964795e+00, 1.90675282e+00],
         [2.51776242e+00, 2.52486706e+00, 2.53197193e+00, ...,
          1.89964795e+00, 1.90675282e+00, 1.90675282e+00],
         [2.53197193e+00, 2.51776242e+00, 2.52486706e+00, ...,
          1.91385746e+00, 1.90675282e+00, 1.90675282e+00]]],


       [[[7.13270283e+00, 7.11016369e+00, 7.13270283e+00, ...,
          4.85625362e+00, 4.90133190e+00, 4.94641018e+00],
         [7.08762503e+00, 7.08762503e+00, 7.08762503e+00, ...,
          4.92387104e+00, 4.96894932e+00, 4.96894932e+00],
         [7.08762503e+00, 7.08762503e+00, 7.06508589e+00, ...,
          4.99148846e+00, 4.96894932e+00, 4.96894932e+00]]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Now firstly I'm trying to normalize by color channel. As each color channel is completely different so I'm normalizing by color channel as follows, dara_array is my whole dataset:

```
def nan(index):
    data_array[:, :, :, index] = (data_array[:, :, :, index] - np.min(data_array[:, :, :, index]))/(np.max(data_array[:, :, :, index]) - np.min(data_array[:, :, : ,index]))
```

Splitting for training, validation and testing:

```
rand_indices = np.random.permutation(len(data))
train_indices = rand_indices[0:19000]
valid_indices = rand_indices[19000:21000]
test_indices = rand_indices[21000:len(data)]

x_val = data_array[valid_indices, :]
y_val = EDR[[valid_indices]].astype('float')

x_train = data_array[train_indices, :]
y_train = EDR[[train_indices]].astype('float')

x_test = data_array[test_indices, :]
y_test = EDR[[test_indices]].astype('float')
```

Then I'm using Imagedatagenerator to fit the training data like this:

```
gen = ImageDataGenerator(
            rotation_range=40,
            zoom_range=0.2,
            shear_range=0.2,
            width_shift_range=0.2,
            height_shift_range=0.2,
            fill_mode='nearest',
            horizontal_flip=True,
    )
gen.fit(x_train)
```

Then I'm using RESNET to train the data as follows:

```
img_height,img_width = 178, 178 
num_classes = 2

base_model = applications.resnet.ResNet101(weights= None, include_top=False, input_shape= (img_height,img_width,3))

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dropout(0.7)(x)
predictions = Dense(1, activation= 'sigmoid')(x)
model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = predictions)

initial_learning_rate = 0.001
def lr_step_decay(epoch, lr):
    drop_rate = 0.5
    epochs_drop = 10.0
    return initial_learning_rate * math.pow(drop_rate, math.floor(epoch/epochs_drop))

sgd = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.001, momentum = 0.9, decay = 1e-6, nesterov=False)
opt_rms = optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001,decay=1e-6)

model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer = sgd, metrics = ['accuracy'])
history = model.fit_generator(gen.flow(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 64), 64, epochs = 30, verbose=1, validation_data=(x_val, y_val),
                   callbacks=[LearningRateScheduler(lr_step_decay)])
```

And here's how my model is training:

```
Epoch 1/30
64/64 [==============================] - 46s 713ms/step - loss: 0.5535 - accuracy: 0.8364 - val_loss: 6.0887 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 2/30
64/64 [==============================] - 43s 671ms/step - loss: 0.4661 - accuracy: 0.8562 - val_loss: 0.6467 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 3/30
64/64 [==============================] - 43s 673ms/step - loss: 0.4430 - accuracy: 0.8640 - val_loss: 0.4231 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 4/30
64/64 [==============================] - 45s 699ms/step - loss: 0.4327 - accuracy: 0.8674 - val_loss: 0.3895 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 5/30
64/64 [==============================] - 43s 677ms/step - loss: 0.4482 - accuracy: 0.8559 - val_loss: 0.3607 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 6/30
64/64 [==============================] - 43s 678ms/step - loss: 0.3857 - accuracy: 0.8677 - val_loss: 0.4244 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 7/30
64/64 [==============================] - 43s 677ms/step - loss: 0.4308 - accuracy: 0.8623 - val_loss: 0.4049 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 8/30
64/64 [==============================] - 43s 677ms/step - loss: 0.3776 - accuracy: 0.8711 - val_loss: 0.3580 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 9/30
64/64 [==============================] - 43s 677ms/step - loss: 0.4005 - accuracy: 0.8672 - val_loss: 0.3689 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 10/30
64/64 [==============================] - 43s 676ms/step - loss: 0.3977 - accuracy: 0.8828 - val_loss: 0.3513 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 0.0010
Epoch 11/30
64/64 [==============================] - 43s 675ms/step - loss: 0.4394 - accuracy: 0.8682 - val_loss: 0.3491 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 5.0000e-04
Epoch 12/30
64/64 [==============================] - 43s 676ms/step - loss: 0.3702 - accuracy: 0.8779 - val_loss: 0.3676 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 5.0000e-04
Epoch 13/30
64/64 [==============================] - 43s 678ms/step - loss: 0.3904 - accuracy: 0.8706 - val_loss: 0.3621 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 5.0000e-04
Epoch 14/30
64/64 [==============================] - 43s 677ms/step - loss: 0.3579 - accuracy: 0.8765 - val_loss: 0.3483 - val_accuracy: 0.8760 - lr: 5.0000e-04
```

My validation accuracy is not changing at all, it's remaining constant. And probably it's predicting everything as 0 cause that'll be the exact accuracy of validation data if it predicts everything as 0 as per split(248 1's out of total 2k val record). Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Sample plot of one file with 5 time dim(I'm just using 1 for training) and 1 channel from data:

[image]

Comment: As you said, your data is imbalanced, that might be the reason why your model is predicting everything as 0. I don't know how to avoid this, but I think using `weights = 'imagenet'` would help.

Comment: @AdarshWase please check the sample image which I have attached, I have satellite Images so I thing adding weights of imagenet won't help! Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: You are correct. `imagenet` weights won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Your observation is indeed correct : the network is not learning anything.

Ensure that your dataset is properly labelled + you feed your data correctly. At the same time, ask&answer the following question: is 178x178 a sufficient resolution for the "other" class that I am trying to detect? If you have already undergone those processes, proceed to the following suggestions.

I would try to start to decrease the learning rate to `0.0001` or `0.00001`(although at this point the learning could converge too slowly).

At the same time could you remove the `Dropout()` altogether to see if your network at least is able to learn anything. At least at this point of investigation `Dropout()` is not needed, it actually hampers the learning due to the high dropout value used.